# iOS 4 Location Service Prompt Dialog Doesn't Show Up

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm experiencing an issue with how iOS 4 manage Location Service. Previously, when the location service is disabled, any application that uses location service will prompt the user to turn it on. However, in iOS 4, it didn't prompt that dialog box and just stays quiet. Is there a way to call the default dialog box which ask the user to turn on the location service, or did they remove that and requires the developers to create their own dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user doesn't want any apps to know their location, you shouldn't nag them. The user can also disable location services for specific apps.

Comment: Well, yes I do understand that. However, my application caters for a wide-range of user-types, including the non-tech savvy. What if a user turned off the Location Service at the very first time by accident, and never knew what he/she just did because iOS4 keeps quiet all the time.

Comment: iOS caters for a wide range of user types. Apple Knows Best, or something. Ultimately, there are much better ways of reporting the error than yet another spontaneous modal dialog, like a label/button which displays a dialog when tapped. If your app is completely unusable without location services, then you have plenty of UI space to populate with error messages. I don't think it's possible to open Settings to the LS page, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to detect this behavior with Javascript in the browser - the error returned has a different code and message - so I imagine that there's a way to do this with an actual app as well.

Not an Obj-C coder, though, so can't actually help out with details. :)